# Jetty: Stopping programatically causes "1 threads could not be stopped"

Tags: java, jetty, shutdown

I have an embedded Jetty 6.1.26 instance.
I want to shut it down by HTTP GET sent to `/shutdown`.
So I created a `JettyShutdownServlet`:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

 resp.setStatus(202, "Shutting down.");
 resp.setContentType("text/plain");
 ServletOutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
 os.println("Shutting down.");
 os.close();
 resp.flushBuffer();

 // Stop the server.
 try {
    log.info("Shutting down the server...");
    server.stop();
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Error when stopping Jetty server: "+ex.getMessage(), ex);
 }
```

However, when I send the request, Jetty does not stop - a thread keeps hanging in `org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool` on the line with `this.wait()`:

```
   // We are idle
   // wait for a dispatched job
   synchronized (this)
   {
       if (_job==null)
          this.wait(getMaxIdleTimeMs());
       job=_job;
       _job=null;
   }
```

...

```
2011-01-10 20:14:20,375 INFO  org.mortbay.log jetty-6.1.26
2011-01-10 20:14:34,756 INFO  org.mortbay.log Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:17283
2011-01-10 20:25:40,006 INFO  org.jboss.qa.mavenhoe.MavenHoeApp Shutting down the server...
2011-01-10 20:25:40,006 INFO  org.mortbay.log Graceful shutdown SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:17283
2011-01-10 20:25:40,006 INFO  org.mortbay.log Graceful shutdown org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context@1672bbb{/,null}
2011-01-10 20:25:40,006 INFO  org.mortbay.log Graceful shutdown org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@18d30fb{/jsp,file:/home/ondra/work/Mavenhoe/trunk/target/classes/org/jboss/qa/mavenhoe/web/jsp}
2011-01-10 20:25:43,007 INFO  org.mortbay.log Stopped SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:17283
2011-01-10 20:25:43,009 WARN  org.mortbay.log 1 threads could not be stopped
2011-01-10 20:26:43,010 INFO  org.mortbay.log Shutdown hook executing
2011-01-10 20:26:43,011 INFO  org.mortbay.log Shutdown hook complete
```

It blocks for exactly one minute, then shuts down.
I've added the Graceful shutdown, which should allow me to shut the server down from a servlet; However, it does not work as you can see from the log.

I've solved it this way:

```
Server server = new Server( PORT );
server.setGracefulShutdown( 3000 );
server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
...
server.start();

if( server.getThreadPool() instanceof QueuedThreadPool ){
   ((QueuedThreadPool) server.getThreadPool()).setMaxIdleTimeMs( 2000 );
}
```

`setMaxIdleTimeMs()` needs to be called after the `start()`, becase the threadPool is created in `start()`. However, the threads are already created and waiting, so it only applies after all threads are used at least once.

I don't know what else to do except some awfulness like interrupting all threads or `System.exit()`.

Any ideas? Is there a good way?

Comment: I've found what seems to discuss the problem - http://osdir.com/ml/java.jetty.general/2003-10/msg00074.html - however, still the grateful shutdown should handle this IMO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Graceful doesn't do what you think it does - it allows the server to shutdown gracefully, but it *does not* allow you to shutdown from inside a servlet.

The problem is as described in the mailing-list post you linked to - you're trying to stop the server, while you're still processing a connection inside the server.

You should try changing your servlet's implementation to:

```
// Stop the server.
new Thread()
{
   public void run() {
     try {
        log.info("Shutting down the server...");
        server.stop();
        log.info("Server has stopped.");
     } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error when stopping Jetty server: "+ex.getMessage(), ex);
     }
   }
}.start();
```

That way the servlet can finished processing while the server is shutting down, and will not hold up the shutdown process.

Comment: This solution works. However, I had to add `Thread.sleep()` to prevent the same happening - the thread was executed too soon. So I wonder how to block it until the request thread ends. `join()` does not work since the thread goes back to the pool.

Comment: @Ondra Žižka Not sure if this is still relevant, but pls consider an answer at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719159/programmatic-jetty-shutdown/9704012#9704012

Comment: Wonderful, but still need a way to handle Thread.sleep() mentioned by @OndraŽižka